# Displaying custom actuator endpoints in springboot admin

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I would like to display my custom actuator endpoint for an application registered with springboot admin.

By default it only displays health, management and service url's.

Is there a way to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: An example of adding custom tabs in spring boot admin server for custom endpoints : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53462345/1131967

Answer (score 0):

you can add your own views. But there is no guide on that. Look at the source of https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/tree/master/spring-boot-admin-server-ui-activiti should give you the basic idea.